# Extending Python 3.5 (Windows) with C++

Tags: python, cython

My goal is to have the ability to call functions in C++ with meaningful arguments.

I can't do that with just subprocess.call because then I go into main(int argc,char** argv) and I have a bunch of strings to deal with. I do not want to have to parse matrices out of strings.

I'm trying to use Cython because that seems like the reasonable thing to do. But although there are a good amount of guides for getting Cython running most of them are for 2.7, and it's rare to see two advise the same thing.

My question basically is does anybody here know how to get Cython running on Py3.5? Or know of a guide or something? I'm lost.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `ctypes` module, if you're trying to call C++ code from Python?

Comment: It might be as easy as `pip3 install cython` so maybe some more research effort? See http://blog.behnel.de/posts/whats-new-in-cython-023.html

Comment: Installing cython never was a problem. The problem is understanding how to actually use it. So far it seems like you have a .pyx file where you have your python/c++ code, you compile it from the cmd line with the help of a setup.py file and mingw32. The problem is knowing what to put in the setup.py file and getting mingw32 to compile the .pyx file correctly. That's not working for me, I've tried different things from different guides and different things are going wrong each time. That's why I'm asking for a working guide. `pip3 install cython` is like the first 5% of the things you require.

Comment: There are plenty of good guides around. Most likely you've given up too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I had a pretty silly mistake, was compiling with msvs, spent **so** much time trying to get mingw to work but forget that, 'msvc' does the trick. For any passersby if you're on 3.5+ you should be using Visual Studio 2015. After installing cython with 'pip3 install cython', create a setup.py file where you put this

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "TestCython.pyx",                 # our Cython source
       #sources=["Rectangle.cpp"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
  ))
```

Create a .pyx file (let's say 'TestCython.pyx') where you write whatever you want for example (let's say 'print("Hello World")'. The sources argument for cythonize is optional.

Then cd into where your .pyx and .py file is and run
'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=msvc'

This should compile to a .cpp and then .pyd file (the latter is the one you will use). If you just had the hello world that will get printed out as soon as you import TestCython.

Refer to the docs and google for anything else. ;)